# Blackberry facebook SDK login browser error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, blackberry, authentication, java-me, blackberry-simulator

I recently switched from using the BlackBerry Facebook SDK jar to using the project's source code (checked out from the tag that the jar was built from).

Ever since this switch, I've experienced `BrowserField` problems:

On a device, the loading graphics persists until I back out.

On a simulator I see:

> Error requesting content for
>
> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_events,user_groups,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_notes,user_online_presence,user_photo_video_tags,user_photos,user_relationships,user_relationship_details,user_religion_politics,user_status,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history,email,read_friendlists,read_insights,read_mailbox,read_requests,read_stream,xmpp_login,ads_management,user_checkins,friends_about_me,friends_activities,friends_birthday,friends_education_history,friends_events,friends_groups,friends_hometown,friends_interests,friends_likes,friends_location,friends_notes,friends_online_presence,friends_photo_video_tags,friends_photos,friends_relationships,friends_relationship_details,friends_religion_politics,friends_status,friends_videos,friends_website,friends_work_history,manage_friendlists,friends_checkins,publish_stream,create_event,rsvp_event,offline_access,publish_checkins,manage_pages&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&display=wap&client_id=[APPLICATION_ID]&response_type=token
>
> Error message null.

where `APPLICATION_ID` is my correct application ID.

The above URL opens fine in my PC browser, and I have debugged for a while through the Facebook sdk's source and found nothing.

It is possible that the application id might have changed recently without me knowing, and my next step is to revert back to using the .jar just for testing purposes.

Has anyone seen similar behavior with the BlackBerry SDK before?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what happened in your case, but I've seen that error when the ProtocolController is set before the BrowserField is initialized. Like so:

```
private BrowserField bf;
...
BrowserFieldConfig bfc = new BrowserFieldConfig();
// bf not initialized yet but no compiler error
bfc.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.CONTROLLER, new ProtocolController(bf){
    public void handleNavigationRequest(BrowserFieldRequest request) throws Exception {
        super.handleNavigationRequest(request);
    }

    public InputConnection handleResourceRequest(BrowserFieldRequest request) throws Exception {
        return super.handleResourceRequest(request);
    }
});
bf = new BrowserField(bfc);
add(bf);
bf.requestContent("http://www.google.com");
...
```

Simply setting the ProtocolController after the BrowserField is initialized but before content is requested solves it.